# MVC 6 - Prevent Cache After Logout

Tags: caching, model-view-controller, asp.net-identity

I'm using MVC 6 and I have implemented Identity 3.0 for authentication.

I'm trying to prevent the user from clicking on the browser back button after logout. The closest working solution I came across seems to be not working in MVC 6.

Could someone help?

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method)]
public sealed class NoCacheAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
public override void OnResultExecuting(ResultExecutingContext filterContext)
{
    filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(-1));
    filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Cache.SetValidUntilExpires(false);
    filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Cache.SetRevalidation(HttpCacheRevalidation.AllCaches);
    filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
    filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Cache.SetNoStore();

    base.OnResultExecuting(filterContext);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use it.

```
    [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method)]
    public sealed class NoCacheAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
    {
        public override void OnResultExecuting(ResultExecutingContext filterContext)
        {
            filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Headers.Add("Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"); // HTTP 1.1.
            filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Headers.Add("Pragma", "no-cache"); // HTTP 1.0.
            filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Headers.Add("Expires", "-1"); // Proxies.

            base.OnResultExecuting(filterContext);
        }
    }
```